# Can I use Erlang pg2 for pubsub?

Tags: erlang, publish-subscribe, instant-messaging

Can I use Erlang pg2 for pubsub?

1. Start a process for every client, and `erlang:register()` the process using the email of the client user.
2. Create a process group for every topic, for a client to subscribe to a topic, make the client's process `pg2:join()` the corresponding process group.
3. To send a public a message to a topic, just send the message to the corresponding process group.

Is this feasible? How does this scale? Will this work with millions of clients and millions of topics?

Answer (score 1):

Who cares if it scales? It is more important getting the basics of your system up and running so you begin getting an understanding of the problem at hand. Usually, scale requires you to bake your own solutions, but you also need to understand what the bottlenecks are.

Comment: Should have a been a comment, not an answer, as it answers non of the questions.